# Rest Service Post Calls Not working with Spring Webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-rest, spring-webclient

I need to invoke a rest service asynchronously and I thought of using spring reactive's webclient instead of the AsyncRestTemplate. However my url is not getting invoked at all with the below code.

```
Mono<Test> asyncResponse = webClientBuilder.build().post().uri(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("h1", h1).header("h2", h2)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Test.class);
```

However if I do the same synchronously everything works fine.

```
webClientBuilder.build().post().uri(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("h1", h1).header("h2", h2)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                .exchange();`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exchange` doesn't mean synchronous. It responds `Mono`. You need to `subscribe()` or `block()` your stream somewhere.

Difference with `exchange` and `retrieve` is : They differ in return types; the exchange method provides a ClientResponse along with its status, headers while the retrieve method is the shortest path to fetching a body directly. you can refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient#4-getting-a-response)